# How to read a file from computer using "Choose a file " in Html and store the file contents in a variable using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to read a text file content in my computer into a variable using HTML/JAVASCRIPT "Choose a file" using accept=" text/plain".And print the variable value ie content of a file on screen and I  also have  need in using the variable for other purposes. Ie The following code is not producing output, the contents of the file is not getting transferred to the variable b during b=fa(event);.Can somebody help me in transforming the below code ?

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="prototype"   action="pro.html"  method="post">

<input type='file'  accept='text/plain' ><br>
<input type="submit" onsubmit="pass()" value="submit" />
<div id='output'>

</form>

 <script>

 function pass()
 {
 var b;
 b=fa(event);
 document.write("\n  <br> <br> Contents=   ",b);
 }


 function fa(event) {
    var input = event.target;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var a;
    reader.onload = function(){
    var text = reader.result;
    var node = document.getElementById('output');
    node.innerText = text;
    a=reader.result.substring(0, 200);
    return a;
    }

    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);

     } 



     </script>



     </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Java isn't JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

There are muliple issues with your code

First You have to understand that `reader.onload` function is asynchronous and executes at a later point after calling fa function

So  `b=fa(event);`  doesnt asingn contents of files to var b

Other problems and suggestions are written in snippet itself

NB : if you want to display contents of file only after form submit use can use callback

```
  //pass an anonymous  function to fa function 
  fa(function(result){
    var fileConent;
    fileConent = result;
    console.log(fileConent)
    //execute whatever you want to do 
  });
```

And in fa function

```
function fa(callback) {

    var input = document.getElementById("fileInput")

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var a;
    reader.onload = function(){
    var text = reader.result;
    var node = document.getElementById('output');
    node.innerText = text;
    a=reader.result.substring(0, 200);
    //executes function passed as parameter 
    // now you will get contents in pass function 
    callback(a)
    }

    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);

}
```

Dont forget to add id fileInput to input type='file'

```js
//declare fileConent as global so that any function can access it
var fileConent;

function pass(event)
 {
  //prevent submitting the form else you will jump to "pro.html" and you miss what you want before submitting form
  event.preventDefault();
  //on submit do hwtever you want with file content
  document.write("\n  <br> <br> Contents=   ",fileConent);
 }




function fa(event) {
    var input = event.target;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    //var a;
    reader.onload = function(){
    var text = reader.result;
    var node = document.getElementById('output');
    node.innerText = text;
    //set contents of file in global variable so pass function   can acess it 
    fileConent=reader.result.substring(0, 200);
    
    //return function doesnt work beacuse onload functioin is asynchronous
    //return a;
    }

    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<!-- onsubmit is attribute of  form not submit button -->
<form name="prototype"   action="pro.html"  method="post"  onsubmit="pass(event)">
<!-- added onchange handler as fa function to file input  
beacuse it is better to display contents of file on file input cahnge tan on form submit-->
<input type='file'  accept='text/plain' onchange="fa(event)" ><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
<div id='output'></div>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what was changed and why?

Comment: Sorry Im a very  late but  I commented Changes

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you never stopped your form from submitting using `event.preventDefault()`, and so your form submitted without the JavaScript having time to take effect.

The better way to do this is to catch the `submit` event triggered when you submit a form, and adding your own custom code to it. Here's an example:

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit)  // Attach `handeSubmit` func to `submit` event

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  // Prevent form from submitting
    
    var input = this.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
    var output = document.getElementById('output');

    var reader = new FileReader();
    /* var a */;
    
    reader.onload = function(){
      output.innerText = reader.result;
      /* a=reader.result.substring(0, 200);
      return a; */
      
      // Whatever you need to do last can be done here.
    }

    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<form name="prototype" action="pro.html" method="post">
  <input type='file' accept='text/plain' />
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<div id='output'>
```